# How to work on my java eclipse project from two PCs?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working on a java project (a minecraft plugin for my server) for some time now on my home PC. I use eclipse and have a local maven repository... as well as some repositories online. My effective pom.xml is here, if it helps (http://pastebin.com/D25qN0cY).

The last time I went traveling for a while, I relocated my eclipse project to a folder on my dropbox account...  then installed eclipse on my laptop, and pointed it to that folder. It worked OK.

But a few months later, I went back to my laptop to work on the project and it really messed things up - I'm fairly certain some project files got overwritten / backdated and I had to get things up to date again.

So my question: what is the simplest way to achieve being able to work on my project from my home PC and my laptop? Please note I am not a git expert if that is the solution here and I have a feeling it is. So any guidance on the right direction to go would be appreciated - if that is the answer.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: If this is really your pom file this contains hard coded folders which will not work anyway. You have to follow the default structure work in the folder layout.

Comment: Use any form of collaboration/repository software, or, as a less-smart alternative (less versioning support, etc.) use simple synchronization software and sync every time you finish working from either location.  I for one used CVS on my server for quite some time because the commenting process was exactly what i needed, and I was able to distinguish between versions easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use a [git](https://bitbucket.org/) repo.

Having a code repository has many advantages. It will not just help you working from two different locations, but:

- gives you the ability to rollback your changes if something went wrong
- gives you the ability to *temporarily* rollback your changes if you want to know when did something go wrong :)
- acts as a perfect backup
- opens up the possibility to collaborate with colleagues/friends
- gives you history on your own changes

etc.

If you need help with getting started, bitbucket also has good tutorials, like this:
[Getting started](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using **[Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)**. To start off, you can do the following:

1. Install **[Git client](http://git-scm.com/downloads)** for your OS. This is important because it would help you to get acquainted with the **[basic git commands](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)** on the command prompt/terminal.
2. Install the **[Git plugin for eclipse](http://eclipse.org/egit/download/)** from the marketplace if the eclipse version you are using doesn't have it.
3. You can create a **[Github account](https://github.com/)** where you **[set up a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)** which will act as a remote repository.

Then you can either

- Use git push to push the changes from your local(PC/laptop) repository to the remote repository or,
- Use git pull to fetch remote changes to your local repository or use the git clone command to clone the entire remote repository itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you did with dropbox should work just fine. There is really no reason why this shouldn't work with dropbox or any other cloud service.

But as you suspected, the nicest way to do this is probably git. I'm definitely not a git expert either, as I just use it for version control on my own projects, but it really isn't that difficult to set up. I personally picked up the basics from this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-version-control-with-git--net-7449

For what you want to do, you'd just have to follow that tutorial once to set things up, and then remember no more than the commit, push and pull commands. And if you ever need any of the other functionality (such as when you accidentally break your project) you can just look up how to use it then.